# python regex error: unbalanced parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I pretty new to python, so i have a dictionary with some keys in it, and a string. I have to replace the string if a pattern found in the dictionary exists in the string. both the dictionary and string are very large. I'm using a regex to find the patterns.

It all works fine until a key like this pops up '-(' or this '(-)' in which case python gives an error for unbalanced parenthesis.

Here's how the code I've written looks:

```
somedict={'-(':'value1','(-)':'value2'}
somedata='this is some data containing -( and (-)'
for key in somedict.iterkeys():
    somedata=re.sub(key, 'newvalue', somedata)
```

Here's the error I've got in the console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

I've also tried it many ways using the regex compiler and searched a lot but didn't find anything addressing the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to *escape* the key using [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
somedata = re.sub(re.escape(key), 'newvalue', somedata)
```

otherwise the contents will be interpreted as a regular expression.

You are not using regular expressions at all here, so you may as well just use:

```
somedata = somedata.replace(key, 'newvalue')
```

If you wanted to replace only *whole words* (so with whitespace or punctuation markes around them, at the start or end of the input string), you need to some kind of boundary anchors, at which point it makes sense to use regular expressions. If all you have are alphanumeric words (plus underscores), `\b` would work:

```
somedata = re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(key)), 'newvalue', somedata)
```

This puts `\b` before and after the string you wanted to replace, so that `baz` in `foo baz bar` is changed, but `foo bazbaz bar` is *not*.

For input that involves non-alphanumeric 'words', you'd need to match whitespace-or-start and whitespace-or-end anchors with look-aheads and look-behinds:

```
somedata = re.sub(r'(?:^|(?<=\s)){}(?:$|(?=\s))'.format(re.escape(key)), 'newvalue', somedata)
```

Here the pattern `(?:^|(?<=\s))` uses *two* anchors, the start-of-string anchor and a look-behind assertion, to match the places where there is either the start of the string or a space immediately to the left. Similarly `(?:$|(?=\s)` does the same for the other end, matching the end of the string or a position followed by a space.

Comment: thank you so much Martijn, it does work.However it also replaces the the substrings if somedata='-(-(' converts to 'newvaluenewvalue' how can i avoid it. I only want it to be replaced when the entire string is matched. i.e somedata should remain unchanged if it doesn't match exactly.

Comment: Then just test for equality instead? `if somedata == key: somedata = 'newvalue'` does what you just described too.

Comment: what if 'somedata='this is somedata'' and the key was 'is' that doesn't seem to work there. 'somedata.replace' also replaces the substrings so it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @JosyulaKrishna: You are not explaining yourself very well. Did you want to replace strings that are *whole words* perhaps? So with whitespace around them or at the start or end of a sentence?

Comment: Really? But `-(` are not in `\w`, `\b` should behave weirdly.

Comment: @Martijn and Pavel, Oops i was a bit too fast on that decision, it works for strings but not for this. here's an example. 
'somedata='-(-( -(''
'for key in somedict.iterkeys():
    somedata=re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(key)),'dog',somedata)
'
doesn't seem to do anything, it fails to replace the final '-(' in the string

Comment: @JosyulaKrishna: That is because Pavel is correct that `\b` only works with the boundary between word and non-word characters. I'll update.

Comment: @JosyulaKrishna: you'll have to be much more specific about what is a word boundary in your case. If we look for spaces, normal words followed by punctuation won't be replaced. If we look for non-word characters, keys that are technically punctuation (non-word themselves) will not be replaced.

Comment: @JosyulaKrishna: Updated to use a more sophisticated anchoring. You do need to be *specific* in your questions as to what should be replaced and what should not. Examples would have been helpful.

Comment: @Martijn:Thanks Martijn!! It now works as desired i've tested it on word and non-alphanumeric data.

Comment: @Pavel:Thank you for the help Pavel, in my case a word can start with a space followed by,or without a space. the word can be anything alphanumeric and non-alphabetic,i fell upon this problem while solving an assignment from Coursera's NLP Class.

Comment: @JosyulaKrishna: note that this version (asserting whitespace) won't replace e.g. `word` in `word, word, word.`.

Comment: @PavelAnossov: indeed, but adding punctuation as needed to the look-ahead and look-behind is not that hard in this case; `(?=[\s.,;;])` would allow for more than just whitespace.

Comment: @Pavel: Thank You Pavel, I understand that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `re` for something so simple — just replace:

```
somedata = somedata.replace(key, 'newvalue')
```

That said, if you're constructing a regexp from something, use [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape special characters:

```
somedata=re.sub(re.escape(key), 'newvalue', somedata)
```

Comment: thank you so much Pavel!! It works!! but also replaces the the substrings like '-(-(' converts to 'newvaluenewvalue' how can i avoid it. I only want it to be replaced when the entire string is matched.

Comment: You'll need to formulate exactly what you mean by "entire string". `-(` isn't exactly a "word".

Comment: I meant that regex shouldn't be substituting if a substring is matched. like here's an example: 'data='thisdog has a dog'' and  'data=re.sub(re.escape('dog'),'cat',data)' then 'data='thiscat has a cat' ,which shouldn't happen. the result should've been 'data='thisdog has a cat' .i want to replace it only when the entire string is matched not just a part of it.

Comment: So do you mean it must be preceded and followed by a space?

Comment: doesn't have to be followed by a space ,but yes should be preceded by one.