# How To Fix Unbalanced Parenthesis Error When Replacing String

Tags: python, string, parentheses

When I replace String in a Python DataFrame I get ***unbalanced parenthesis error***.

```
options= ['Electronic finger and face scan)','1) Electronic (Face / Finger scan) of May 2018 to November 2018 (from November 1st to November 10th, 2018) and since January 2019 to May 20192) Manual records in November 2018 (from November 11th to November 30th, 2018) and December 2018.']

dict = {'Options': options}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 

    df.replace('^1) Electronic (Face / Finger scan) of May 2018 to November 2018 (from November 1st to November 10th, 2018) and since January 2019 to May 20192) Manual records in November 2018 (from November 11th to November 30th, 2018) and December 2018.$', 'Mixed', regex=True, inplace=True)

    df.replace('^Electronic finger and face scan)$', 'Electronic', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

I'd highly value any suggestion or help.

Comment: I'm working in Python. Just edit and specified the programming language.

Comment: dummy dataframe added

Comment: general tip: provide minimal examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python regex error: unbalanced parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947140/python-regex-error-unbalanced-parenthesis)

Answer (score 0):

In your example you set `regex = True`, which means the string to be replaced it read as regex. Since parentheses in regex have a specific mean (see [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)), you need to escape all parenthesis that are supposed to be read as purely characters.
E.g.:

```
df.replace('a)','a', regex=True)
```

should be:

```
df.replace('a\)','a', regex=True)
```